# Sign-Swapping Sums

Tags: code-golf, math, combinatorics

Given a nonempty list of positive integers \$(x, y, z, \dots)\$, your job is to determine the number of unique values of \$\pm x \pm y \pm z \pm \dots\$

For example, consider the list \$(1, 2, 2)\$. There are eight possible ways to create sums:

- \$+ 1 + 2 + 2 \to +5\$
- \$+ 1 + 2 − 2 \to +1\$
- \$+ 1 − 2 + 2 \to +1\$
- \$+ 1 − 2 − 2 \to −3\$
- \$− 1 + 2 + 2 \to +3\$
- \$− 1 + 2 − 2 \to −1\$
- \$− 1 − 2 + 2 \to −1\$
- \$− 1 − 2 − 2 \to −5\$

There are six unique sums \$\{5, -5, 1, -1, 3, -3\}\$, so the answer is \$6\$.

### Test Cases

```
[1, 2] => 4
[1, 2, 2] => 6
[s]*n => n+1
[1, 2, 27] => 8
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] => 29
[3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5] => 45
[1, 7, 2, 8, 3, 1, 6, 8, 10, 9] => 56
[93, 28, 92, 100, 43, 66, 2, 98, 2, 52, 57, 75, 39, 77, 45, 15, 13, 82, 81, 20, 68, 14, 5, 3, 72, 56, 57, 1, 23, 25, 76, 59, 60, 71, 71, 24, 1, 3, 72, 84, 72, 28, 83, 62, 66, 45, 21, 28, 49, 57, 70, 3, 44, 47, 1, 54, 53, 56, 36, 20, 99, 9, 89, 74, 1, 14, 68, 47, 99, 61, 46, 26, 69, 21, 20, 82, 23, 39, 50, 58, 24, 22, 48, 32, 30, 11, 11, 48, 90, 44, 47, 90, 61, 86, 72, 20, 56, 6, 55, 59] => 4728
```

[Reference solution](https://tio.run/##lVJNT4NAFLzzK16MhzZdDR/LshjryYuJiQePhAOmaBtxaYQqB/97nXFRE6MNEh67@/bNm5kX1lX3WDfNfr952rbPvVxWfXV6vel6mbnd3TwI6mFbuZWcnUlx5fpSTi4EK5eP8@f90MkgSwFGjmXVipPzEyQD@f0pnCxkUChDVRkEXdu81D9JxuxSmto99Gs5lfu2WTUyUhYhgE/VxhF3dSOzuT8tZbvrb/tnCNm5ZuPqDruiW7evkLhYyJEsL/DB7iM38yzD/C@tfN4AhaGiiJTEpTpU@mWRpf@q/n7/xZAo0UpSJUZJNhGZAxRbJXmsojBEA5wN8OyXW7@mjAw90TrJsWKvsY8YqLe4t5QQTuIUg74RlFIqRWfsbzwHXcfUhLuMOfAZ6MoiH7H2NZ84q6dxspY@Lf3F3iM9xJHP63z0GPreGjx61JNyqonXmJjpPnP0FITlzEbd9E3/7M17g5xmT4TJRz2hnynnwHmnOKd2GifnEwOrwZHwnwA2inwwl4ff3rgnvzV@luSlR/4/acrZl@UB0nK/fwc) (optimizes for speed and not size).

If you can't handle the last case because you use a brute-force method or similar, that's fine.

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest valid solution (measured in bytes) wins.

Comment: Do we have to handle the case where the input is the empty array?

Comment: @ChasBrown the input is non-empty, according to the post.

Comment: Hm, I can't understand how the third test case works, care to explain please?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer It's effectively saying if your array is all identical numbers (e.g. `[2,2,2,2,...]` ) the answer should be the length of the array + 1. This is because in this case the position of the signs is irrelevant and only the number of each matter

Comment: @reffu It's more of a joke, it does look kinda like it has been included there by error.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer It's wasn't intended as a joke; it's an infinite number of test cases!

Comment: With the exception of the `[s]*n` family, all test cases can be computed as *sum of elements plus one*. I suggest adding test cases that fail for this formula (e.g., `[2, 4, 8]` and `[1, 2, 27]`).

Comment: You can use MathJax now!

Answer (score 13):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 27 bytes

```
Tr[1^Fold[#⋃+##&,{0},#]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVLBSsQwEL33KwqBohgxSZNJgih78uzBW6lQVhcXXIWlt9KTR//SH6nzMpVehJ3N9M17My/Tnobx7fU0jMf9sBzuLpanc2efHz7fXzr18/11pVSjJzNr1ffNcnlbPZ6PH2Onru8PO9U3N7upqqrJ6trNWs4t/ee3kVpde10HXZOuI@C2MHz5ZzgXFpWcS2FVxgKngtlS59wa5oOQGXUMZAeQUc8AUdHkVI6A4C4RfXlI5NxzbhHMTmgPi6wm9PZ/FiKUJGoQMIsrERA3IhZEK@HkGqsoeTnhLMGQE1MY66zgPq@2jKyGJV7mBBhoZXRLYiznsqAE/zIKNmEXIlQJuwSbg/I6x8j14BxXD/wckrh1jHusFa@GcWslgGWzGUKO3onWOxlxhiUELGLm72FefgE)

Finding the number of unique sign-swapping sums is equivalent to finding the number of unique subset sums.

A proof would involve adding the sum of the input to each of the sign-swapping sums and dividing by two. Then, there's an obvious bijection.

#### Explanation

```
Fold[#⋃+##&,{0},#]
```

Iterate through the input, with the initial value being `{0}`: take the union between `<current value>` and `<current value> + input element` (maps onto lists).

```
Tr[1^ ... ]
```

Golfy version of the `Length` function.

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
ŒPS€QL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opIDgR01rAn3@H24H0pH//0dHG@ooGMXqcCmAGahsYx0FEx0FUx0FMx0Fc7A4UMQQLGgIFrcEKzMDs4FSpjC95mBxC7CgIVgBkG1oANQQyxULAA)

#### Background

Let **L** be the input list and **{P, N}** a partition into algebraic summands with positive and negative signs. The challenge spec requires calculating **s<sub>{P,N}</sub> = sum(P) - sum(N)**.

However, since **sum(P) + sum(N) = sum(L)** and **sum(L)** does not depend on the partition, we have **s<sub>{P,N}</sub> = sum(P) - sum(N) = sum(P) - (sum(L) - sum(P)) = 2sum(P) - sum(L)**.

Thus, each unique value of **sum(P)** corresponds to one unique value of **s<sub>{P,N}</sub>**.

#### How it works

```
ŒPS€QL  Main link. Argument: A (array)

ŒP      Powerset; generate all subarrays of A.
  S€    Take the sum of each.
    Q   Unique; deduplicate the sums.
     L  Take the length.
```

Answer (score 7):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
nW:qBGY*un
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/Py/cqtDJPVKrNO///2hDayNro1gA)
This is a port of Luis Mendo's [Octave/MATLAB](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/164527/31516) answer. I'm still trying to learn MATL, and I figured I'd post it, along with an explanation, since MATL is the language of the month.

#### Explanation:

Here's a read-through for anyone unfamiliar with stack based programming in general, and MATL in particular.

The input vector is implicitly placed on the stack. Note that when an operation is performed on an element in the stack, then that element is removed from the stack.

```
                % Stack:
                % [1, 2, 2]
n               % Counts the number of elements of the vector on the top of the stack.
                % Stack:
                % [3]
 W              % Raise 2^x, where x is the number above it in the stack
                % Stack:
                % [8]
  :             % Range from 1...x, where x is the number above it in the stack.                    % Stack:
                % [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
   q            % Decrement. Stack:
                % [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    B           % Convert to binary. Stack:
                % [0,0,0; 0,0,1; 0,1,0; 0,1,1; 1,0,0; 1,0,1; 1,1,0; 1,1,1] 
     G          % Push input again. Stack:           
                % [0,0,0; 0,0,1; 0,1,0; 0,1,1; 1,0,0; 1,0,1; 1,1,0; 1,1,1], [1; 2; 2]
      Y*        % Matrix multiplication of the two elements on the stack.
                % Stack:
                % [0; 2; 2; 4; 1; 3; 3; 5]
        u       % Keep only unique elements. Stack:
                % [0; 2; 4; 1; 3; 5]
         n      % Number of elements in the vector. Stack:
                % [6]
```

And then it outputs the final element on the stack implicitly.

Comment: Nice explanation!

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 55 bytes

```python
s={0}
for n in input():s|={t+n for t in s}
print len(s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVHBbsIwDD3Tr/CtoPXQhDRNKnFk1112mzhsLBNoqK3SooEY3975xZ02qVbsZz/72e2v46Fr9bTv3gNtKM/zadjcynv20UVq6YivP4/LVTN8b27jQ0tIjEgM96yPx3akU2iXw2pibpZ9HY6nQM/xHJpsMcZrQ@ES9oT22SJc9qEfafv0uI2xiw29xfD6Ob2ogvQuS89/b12QKagqyBZUM8qxSpBKqE9FNvmcqoRXJ9QlSKU0@6rkcs57BjXHXgNj0DBgbaJ4l54Kxk1qdOURNfuGfQXjaofu0Mdsi9bmV0ANphU2CjCLMzUgbmSZUCsxLUvMJGfkhTIHQVpEYaxWghs/yyrlLkwxMqeCgLWMXlsR5n06j4N@GQWZkAsSshaXRDWb9fOcUtaDcqxecVw5UasZN7gq/gvjSokB8@WfIPjo7ey8UynKcIQKh9j9AA)

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 52 bytes

```python
k=1
for n in input():k|=k<<n
print bin(k).count('1')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVHBasMwDD03X6FbWggjdh3HDu2xu@6y2@hhyzwaMpJgUtbC/j3TszI2iLD0pCc9KdN9voyDXtrxPdCR8jxf@qPKPsZIA3X4puu83TX997E/HIZsit0w01s3bPvdQzteh3mbq3y3MDHLvi7dZ6DneA1NtpnjvaFwCy2hd7YJtzZMM52eHk8xjrGhtxhe@@VFFaTPWXr@e/uCTEFVQbagmlGOVYJUQn0qssnnVCW8OqEuQSql2Vcll3PeM6g59hoYg4YBaxPFu/RUMG5SoyuPqNk37CsYVzt0hz5mW7Q2vwJqMK2wUYBZnKkBcSPLhFqJaVliJTkjL5Q5CNIiCmO1Etz4VVYpd2GKkTkVBOxl9N6KMO/TeRz0yyjIhFyQkLW4JKrZrF/nlLIelGP1iuPKiVrNuMFV8V8YV0oMmC//BMFHb2fXnUpRhiNUOMT5Bw)

Uses the binary representation of a number to store the reachable subset sums.

Comment: Could you explain how this works? Did you come up with it yourself, or is it some known result?

Comment: @sundar It's not that complicated. This answer calculates the unique sums (not sign-swapping) like many other answers. Each bit in k corresponds to a sum. `k<<n` adds n to each sum. Oring with `k` stores these new sums in `k` whilst keeping all the previous ones, and duplicated Sims are not recorded

Comment: Ah, the trail of breacrumbs leads back to [JungHwan Min's bijection idea](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/164513/8774), that was the main insight I was missing. Here each subset sum is represented by a 1 in that position in the bitstring (with the initial 1 in the LSB representing the sum 0 for the empty subset). Still not something I'd call "not that complicated", but that may just be my inexperience speaking. :)

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
æOÙg
```

Utilizes the same approach used in [Dennis’ Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/164512/59487).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8DL/wzPT//@PNtQx0jGKBQA)

Answer (score 5):

## R, <s>83</s> 75  bytes

#### -8 bytes thanks to JayCe and Giuseppe

Creates a matrix of all possible combinations of (1,-1) for the size of the input vector, multiples this by the original vector to get the sums. Then unique and find the length of the result.

`function(v)nrow(unique(t(t(expand.grid(rep(list(c(1,-1)),sum(v|1)))))%*%v))`

---

#### previous version:

`f=function(v)nrow(unique(as.matrix(expand.grid(rep(list(c(1,-1)),length(v))))%*%v))`

#### Ungolfed with comments:

```
f=function(vector){

  List=rep(list(c(1,-1)),length(vector))   ## Create a list with length(vector) elements, all (1,-1)

  Combinations=expand.grid(Length)    ## get all combinations of the elements of the list, e.g, 1,-1,1,1,-1,1

  Matrix=as.matrix(Combinations)   ## convert to matrix

  Results=Matrix%*%vector   ## multiply the matrix original vector to get a Nx1 matrix

  Unique_results=unique(Results)   ## unique the results

  nrow(Unique_results)   ## length = number of rows of unique values
  }
```

Comment: Save some bytes with `t`: [TIO](https://tio.run/##HYvBCoMwEETv/Yq9CJuyirFQ2@LPiCYakFXTpPXv48aZw7yBGZ8sdGWykYfgVsafYr/@MbLbo8EgNsfW81hN3o3ozYaL@wYcUFOplaLF8BRmuWUV90IgWdSfRt1ytDnyGFqChuBF8CCQ@rxY1wRveZw)

Comment: and `sum(v|1)` is a byte shorter than `length(v)`

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell, 46 bytes

```
import Data.List
length.nub.map sum.mapM(:[0])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYrRCsIgGEbv9xT/5QY/MrO5Fuyuy3oCkTDYmkxNpnt@Uyro6hzO9y0qrJMxKWnrX1uEi4qKXHWI1TyayT3jQtz@IFZ5CLstvNVn0comWaUdjFDKHWq/aReBwNyAqAAExYPEr/wrwyN2yLH/JIY0B5rTkEeeybD7vfucTlguPJO2OEgJ6Q0)

Instead of summing the subsets of the input list, we make all combinations of either keeping a number or replacing it by `0`, e.g.

```
mapM(:[0])[1,2,3] -> [[1,2,3],[1,2,0],[1,0,3],[1,0,0],[0,2,3],[0,2,0],[0,0,3],[0,0,0]]
```

This is two bytes shorter than `subsequences`.

Comment: Nice answer! I hoped something like `f x=sum[1|i<-[0..sum x],elem i$sum<$>mapM(:[0])x]` would be shorter than the import, but apparently, it isn't.

Comment: Nice, even shorter than the translation of the Mathematica one, although I think it’s prettier: `import Data.List;length.foldr((<*>)union.map.(+))[0]`

Answer (score 4):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 39 bytes

```
a->#[1|n<-Vec(prod(i=1,#a,1+x^a[i])),n]
```

Counts the number of nonzero coefficients of the polynomial \$ \prod_{i \in a}(1+x^i) \$, where \$a\$ is the input.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZHdSsQwEIVfJezetJhCJ80vuPsY3pQKQV0pSA3FCwXfvc7JRBYaMvkyZ@ZkWvK@Du/luKnLkYfreabf7XF4envpyv752q0X0ues6eH7Oc/r0vd6W45cysdPl9VwVWVfty8OTzic1K3LnKLmmbQyCwfYW@i1wnenk1ZWK1dxAGZAlVHFqWb5GvOVa8pQcayM6j3HNHI@EhJTwyAZQKaWgfdVk2LdHBZXCajLTQLHlmPC4uyI8rDIao/a9t9CgNKLGgnoxTcBiAt5FgSSZeQZTRSt7HAWYciIKbQ1JNymZmuU0bDESh8HA5O0nrwYS6kOKMK/tIJN2IUItx6zRDamnlqfUZ4H53i647OL4tYwtxgrfg1zIllgabwbQoza0bc3jeIMQ3AYxLL0xx8)

Comment: That's a cool way to do it!

Answer (score 4):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) / MATLAB, <s>45</s> <s>41</s> 40 bytes

```matlab
@(x)nnz(unique(dec2bin(0:2^nnz(x)-1)*x))
```

Input is a column vector (using `;` as separator).

The code errors for the last test case due to memory restrictions.

This uses an idea from [JungHwan Min's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/164513/36398) (subsets instead of alternating signs) to save a few bytes.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0IzL69KozQvs7A0VSMlNdkoKTNPw8DKKA4kXKGpa6ipVaGp@T9NI9rQWsEoVpMLyDK1VoAiCB8kA5eEcIytFUzASsysFcwhEkAhQ7CoIVjCEqzODMw2RjbKHCxhARY1BKsAsg0NgDpiNf8DAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 61 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,s={0}:a and f(a[1:],s|{u+a[0]for u in s})or len(s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVLLboMwELzzFXsEdQ82fmBH4ksQB9oEFSmFKCRSqjTfTmcx6UOw2vXsjHcMPn1e3qfRLEtfH7uP131HHc/1XT12qMY99XnX6F3L89f9@tI1qu2nM11pGGl@FCiPhzGfi@Wtmw8z1dRkRHmjuWyZbMHP1br229ryvwed@IdpgDn2XAEvnw3DGrBGI4LikQ07GeF@lBUagYXokbXiiL57zowGuwVMKpm0UlAC8B4gsLAmJ1ExVY7JRORK9gddAuyAftCgQu0h0RZ8UMEUpU9qIcgsdCqBsJGHoNIpSrtSNlGwKYuzIIbKZErGljrhNm621CqzkNg0x4kBk0Ybn4xFsPEG8Z9GiU2xKyLpemBW2AgftzkqHU@cy9Ed1i4ktyVwi9ogG@BapxAsql9DUsvewW9nUsmZfAQnH0J@V1WGImuzTC7RwDTJPVqvzg5/6Vb3@VCgOJ2H8ZLfmG5U1zQVyzc)

Recursive approach, keeping track of unique subset sums.

The real fun is that this beats `itertools` by a big margin:

### 76 bytes

```python
lambda a:len({*map(sum,product(*([0,x]for x in a)))})
from itertools import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/RCsIwDEXf@xV5bEcenHPVDfYlcw9VNyysS@kqKOK3z1RUlEDCveeGNv4WzzQVy9Dsl9G4w8mAqcd@kvfMGS/ni0Mf6HQ5RpnJdoXXbqAAV7ATGKXUQ4khkAMb@xCJxhms8xRithzN3M/QQCsAZJvjukPYKPyol9ZvvcG/YlL9JAv2StS4ZX/9AQXmbOcMKo5ongWW6Ynyu7llsMMU1DzzFVbMS61EJ0Q6wiJQuuP105qXfLBTlIO0CiF1aBogtTwB)

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 5 bytes

```
l{sMy
```

Utilizes the same approach used in [Dennis’ Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/164512/59487).

[Try it here.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=l%7BsMy&input=%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4%2C+5%2C+6%2C+7%5D&debug=0)

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

-1 thanks to H.PWiz

```apl
≢⊃(+∪⊢)/⎕,0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LVDLTgJBELzvV/RtIEKcmZ2nf7OBQIhEzLIXQzhpENAlJsajBzl61guJP9M/gtWrSc/2THdtVXVXt/Ph@K6aL6bD0bxaLmejMx/eZgvevOiCt4@TM@@OvL/vXfD2k/fH/iXaA31G6zwFiNuD4ecftV6pgUJLTq24/Va83RvevOI9qtVEEbfv1NTVeHJDzYKQigb/rwDl3UeN65Tb05VaXCt@elCTajYHzQntel0YstSQ67LcQtEL3H6lfkOxK5bkyFOgiKbNRUkGBYNSRjMglzhg8EBHlBIJJCAbDUxDPhQVPOSSbKJsUdbkSgoB4Jzw8YhIEUyZYgQTGURJCWRwoCmAy3VKEVBoxqIagBJNkHqKKGUKmqKRsOKvwyYnX8gm6FmRBLk1UnG5E9UynyMXyfxxegiVIlIGkc4ZMyT4Ek6YgBVgUQ1YAxCBQu4YtdiFHczgNfkkLqz943TYCRapyRgJPLP@V8UFTCl0PrXoYhaPcYpKlhpt@gU)

Comment: As has been noted in other answers, `-⍨` can be `⊢`

Comment: @H.PWiz thanks, very nice!

Answer (score 3):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), 29 bytes

```
{#Unique[Flat!±_]}@Fold[`±]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP2fpmBl@79aOTQvs7A0NdotJ7FE8dDG@NhaB7f8nJTohEMbY//7paamFEerFBQkp8dyBRRl5pWEpBaXOCcWpxZHp@koRHMpAEG0oY6CUawOgo3ENdFRQCBUNcZgQVMdBTMdBXOYFFDQECxuCJayBKs0A7OBUqZIJpiDpSzA4oZgNUC2oQFQTyxXbOx/AA)

This works by folding the `±` operator over the input list, then taking `±` of that list, then counting the unique atoms of the array.

Here's some examples of how the folding works:

```
Fold[`±][ [1,2] ] == 1 ± 2
                  == [1 + 2, 1 - 2]
                  == [3, -1]
Fold[`±][ [1,2,2] ] == (1 ± 2) ± 2
                    == [3, -1] ± 2
                    == [[3 + 2, 3 - 2], [-1 + 2, -1 - 2]]
                    == [[5, 1], [1, -3]]
                    == [5, 1, 1, -3]
Fold[`±][ [4,4,4,4] ] == (4 ± 4) ± 4 ± 4
                      == [8, 0] ± 4 ± 4
                      == [[12, 4], [4, -4]] ± 4
                      == [[[16, 8], [8, 0]], [[8, 0], [0, -8]]]
                      == [16, 8, 8, 0, 8, 0, 0, -8]
                      == [16, 8, 0, -8]
```

Then we generate all permutations of the final sign by applying PlusMinus once more.

### A more efficient version, 31 bytes

```
`#@(q:=Unique@Flat@`±)@Fold[q]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RVDLasMwELz7KwTtoQUdLOthKRAwFHIsPbQnY4hJlDYQ0rh2P6y/0B9zZ7yGgpddj2Y0s@qnqT985PmkNtt5f9c8DJvt2/U8fOdmd@mnZv/789jsPi/Hdujm55yPY3t/ux3eu@Ll63ydXvM4PfVjHtuTVm3RJqtVFbVKlVamLLVyAEIACCwuzbNqrWqvlU3omB1mwwI74jwaUKEOkBgHPqhgUhlETQK9cFITwkUBgtpIVW6hrKLopDNZZKBKQtG2MoK7tMYqF5mDxImPZwAr1jZIsAQ2vsj8YsWYjEsRTwMwRzYqpNWnlPWYnKt7/PsoaSvgDrNFt8CNkSKWyv9AnHl3DOtOpSTjI3g@RFd03fwH) This doesn't time out on the final test case, since it doesn't generate unnecessary combinations.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 62 bytes

```r
function(V)sum(unique(c(V%*%combn(rep(0:1,L),L<-sum(V|1))))|1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNMs7g0V6M0L7OwNFUjWSNMVUs1OT83KU@jKLVAw8DKUMdHU8fHRhekKKzGUBMIgOT/NKBSQx0jHSNNzf8A)

Ports Dennis' algorithm. It's closest to the Octave/MATL answers as it uses a similar bitmap and matrix product for inclusion/exclusion of terms.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 39 bytes

```perl
s/^| /{+,-}/g;$_=grep!$s{eval$_}++,glob
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YP65GQb9aW0e3Vj/dWiXeNr0otUBRpbg6tSwxRyW@VltbJz0nP@n/f0MFIwVjBRMFUwUzBfN/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwN/usWAAA)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 63 bytes

```javascript
f=([c,...a],s=n=!(o={}))=>c?f(a,s-c)|f(a,s+c)&&n:o[s]=o[s]||++n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY5BCsIwEEX3niJuSkKnqalNaoXoQUoXJVpRSiJG3FjPHuNQEaSb4cN7f2Yu3aPz5na@3jPrDscQek0bA5zzrgWvrV5Sp58vxvTO7Hvagc8MGzGkhiWJ3brGt/ozxjFNbTDOejcc@eBOtKeNAFK0jJE8J@Vihv2wmsdrICUQCUQBqSa1qP/daAkUBbo1VhXmiOT3Azlzo0J3g6LAUsxiFZdMLanCGw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

```
LumΣṖ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6fq@GlpGBrp6B0aHlqsUbxo6ZGzdyics1D2/77lOaeW/xw57T///8bKhhxATGUNFYwUTBVMFMw5zJWMASyDYE8S6C4GZA2VjAFqjEH8iwUQLJmQNrQQMGSCwA)

Port of [Dennis' Jelly answer.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/164512/59487)

#### Explanation

```
LumΣṖ                     [1,2,2]
    Ṗ  Powerset           [[],[1],[2],[1,2],[2],[1,2],[2,2],[1,2,2]]
  mΣ   Sum each           [0,1,2,3,2,3,4,5]
 u     Remove duplicates  [0,1,2,3,4,5]
L      Length             6
```

Comment: Equivalent to the [Pyth answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/164523/20080), essentially character for character.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 33 bytes

```perl6
{+set ([X](^2 xx$_)XZ*$_,)>>.sum}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/Wrs4tURBIzoiViPOSKGiQiVeMyJKSyVeR9POTq@4NLf2f3FipUKaBlBcIS2/iCvaUEfBKFYHQqMwjXUUTHQUTHUUzHQUzEHCQAFDsJghWNgSrMoMzAZKmUJ1moOFLcBihmB5INvQAKg@1vo/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + GNU utilities, 49 bytes

```bash
eval echo "{,-}${@//,/{+,-\}}\;"|bc|sort -u|wc -l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TUvNCoJAEL77FMNip2axzdJEii7dOkS3wMu6TiiIhmt5UJ/dpj9oYOb7nVTbfOryoiRoSGcxZLUDPC3Z1mhLW@GeD6fjRbzdW1NU7RXEzILcgQDh/nqf3FILUv7bEz10CWTyGkSPcnT7veeh189RJuOYxGJIzWDrhv/uQ2dAllNWVzQpXDq83@vjCtcYYOj4qJgrVhH7AaOPa@6ErDb4SgNGtcDIeQI)

Input given as a comma-separated list at the command-line.

#### Explanation

```bash
               ${@//,/{+,-\}}                      # Replace commas with {+,-}
          "{,-}${@//,/{+,-\}}\;"                   # Build a brace expansion with {+,-} before every number and ; at the end
eval echo "{,-}${@//,/{+,-\}}\;"                   # Expand to give every combination expression, separated by ;
                                |bc                # Arithmetically evaluate each line
                                   |sort -u        # Remove duplicates
                                            wc -l  # Count
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>74</s> 69 bytes

```c
f(a,b)int*a;{long k=1;for(;b--;k|=k<<a[b]);a=__builtin_popcountl(k);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZDfCoIwFIev6ykOQrDFEVr/TJZPYiLTWIg2pfTKfHbbVjcRucYudtjvfN/Ocv@S5@MoicCMFqpdCt5XtbpAGTEu6xvhme/z8hGVx6OIs4RyEaVp1hVVW6i0qZu87lRbkZLyYbyKQhHaz2fNTaMk8SSJF/eEQgSL80l5CB5DWMPE0hlJiO6OE9qDKw0DAqwp5S7lFOdbOWk1yo1DGSKY/afSlf5L@Xr3BmGLsEPYIwTOKX@nrTJwKHU7swRmIaFlapQp9N3uU@lKGyVj7ikD23jAN3Bvz2z1@sCvKSfTVrkyymF8Ag)

C port of @xnor's answer

Answer (score 2):

## x86_64 machine language for Linux, <s>31</s> 29 bytes

```
 0:   31 d2                   xor    %edx,%edx
 2:   6a 01                   pushq  $0x1
 4:   58                      pop    %rax
 5:   8b 0c 97                mov    (%rdi,%rdx,4),%ecx
 8:   48 89 c3                mov    %rax,%rbx
 b:   ff c2                   inc    %edx
 d:   48 d3 e3                shl    %cl,%rbx
10:   48 09 d8                or     %rbx,%rax
13:   39 d6                   cmp    %ese,%edx
15:   7c ee                   jle    5 <+0x5>
17:   f3 48 0f b8 c0          popcnt %rax,%rax
1c:   c3                      retq
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZDdioMwEIWvt08xCIWkpGBM/UP6JMYLjcbtxbqLtRAQn92dxN2LpaypBGcmZ@Z8jurcK7Wu6nO4T6De6xH6sroG0gguTRtJk9TShJjHmTRZg7mSJk@ludg6l0YJabTGGG13Ldad2PIQ9RajwKhRT3G26zD/1XGuwahC6xMUh9swgSb4PtXM5g2dx256jAOxl@REnWYlSntKatbQYlk/6ttA6Hx4@xpR0STQpDzeKwpXOLZyCBgEnEEEOw/2aMcoKzqDrxsWBhBRWviQez7PyF2qRQoPMmdgz4tIX/dLyO27BYMLg5hBwiD1bvl/t0OmHiSOc@fAnUnuPNHKFqjFf5G@bovk3L9l6gYz9mOYuJyH2w982nK32yFDi1zWbw)

Inspired by @xnor's answer. Requires a machine with the `POPCNT` instruction.

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>34</s> <s>33</s> 32 bytes

```apl
{≢∪⍵+.×⍨↑{,⍵∘.,U}⍣(≢1↓⍵)⊢U←¯1 1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@/@lHnokcdqx71btXWOzz9Ue@KR20Tq3WA3EcdM/R0Qmsf9S7WACoxfNQ2GSio@ahrUeijtgmH1hsqGNb@dwMyKTGA61HfVCDHTcFQwUjBCMHTUTDSUTDWUTDRUTDVUTDTUTD/DwA)

Thanks to @ngn for -1 byte!

Comment: `1-⍨≢⍵` -> `≢1↓⍵`

Comment: `+.×⍨` -> `+.×`

Comment: The latter one doesn't work, I'm afraid.

Comment: oops, I don't know why I thought you're applying +.× on vectors... sorry

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl), 82 bytes

```
import StdEnv
f[]=length
f[h:t]=f t o foldr(\e l=removeDup[e+h,e-h:l])[]
?l=f l[0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYw9C8IwFAD3/ooHLooRWgW/ILjUQXBzjBlCmpjAS1LaV8E/b4wubndwnEajYg6pm9BAUD5mH/o0ENyoO8dnZYXkaOKDXEF3JMktECSwCbthfjeAfDAhPU079cIsHTMrd0S5ELI6YWlR1DLfSA1UzQD9SMBBNAx2DNYM9gw2DIpuf9zUDA6yhHaKmnyKJT5V/K/fQX5ri@ox5tXlmttXVMHr8QM)

Defines the function `? :: [Int] -> Int` using `f :: [Int] -> ([Int] -> Int)` as a helper to reduce over each possible sum after an addition or subtraction.

Comment: [Here](https://tio.run/##lU5NS8NAFLznV0xNwYTsltb6cbARSpVUKFIQTyGHtflautkN2Q1G1N8eNxXxZKHD4/EYZuZNyfQ@E6L/oC42y6foZRk9YLXdwqVfDqVYs90eRkEbVSNar5A3qsJOVbVgXHJZwJTM4BEpT@W5AdOaFxKCywzzwcjkuymtznHTLB9YkcnClMhDL1cibby6bTIvmPn@1O95VavG4J4ZNtlwbRw96kLZvo5TBbmg@jaWQUck7RLnJ2YyZAhv5MfTpK9sI4SoW/NsGozRyqGGtlesS/WGDkGAM4R3dtnrwHk5Ot/B//i0tgVFHM8ILhJyTPqLg/Qk9d@c9GFOcElwRXBNcJMkR5xJ/w0)'s a golfed version of the reference solution in Haskell; not sure how much it can carry over to Clean but you might be able to get something out of it.

Comment: @EsolangingFruit Thanks, but it's already using the same approach and I can't find a way to shorten it even with the reference solution golfed.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>207</s> <s>83</s> 44 bytes

```java
s->Long.bitCount(s.reduce(1L,(r,c)->r|r<<c))
```

Port of [@xnor's Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/164577/52210).
-39 bytes thanks to *@Jakob*.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##hVPBbtswDL33K3i0B8e1HFu2kCyXXb1iQI9FD4qjtE4dObDkDkWXb89I0VsvywqEEUU@8j1R8kG/6sVh93Lpjqdh9HDAfTr5rk@/rADg9hZ@aAwPe/DPBrZv3izaYbL@pu21c/Bdd/b9BqCz3ox73Rq4oy1AP9gnaKOPds6PRh/T@7CsG0xvwMUrBJ/R8Oe89l0Ld2DhK1zcYkOYdNv5b8QXuXQ0u6k1kWiSaEzaeLEZf43rdRvHlxV3OE3bHjvMjV6HbgdH1BchZ2efHh5BxyzOG@cja34CUTw8vmPLvDkHMVeSn@erTwDLJimapGwS2STXsYgSASgCVoVSGfwl/f@HowrYOgBFKEJfZNTkWpVCaI4olRMSoQUGpAyNVB2WkgxbV6QA5VToF@gLMkTXxEknxGpJhMUfsRVVSq4mAHFhpqIQNpJYUAm2nA88F9UFr6SsJkE5iyLaXHC8ULOsjCeLJQXzlCRgydRLycKUCqOsST9TkUySS0WUlTR1QqNJNfNkfDxSTkcvcV/WrDbHeEGzppvFuBBsFFPZhyDyqXct5zNlrIyGUIZBnP/xDYSnGy6LL@rvw71/c94c02Hy6QnftO9tZNOrX1k67CMdxzPB@fIb).

```java
s->               // Method with Long-Stream parameter and long return-type
  Long.bitCount(  //  Return the amount of 1s in the binary representation of:
    s.reduce(1L,  //   Result-Long, starting at 1
     (r,c)->      //   Loop pair-wise (result,current):
      r|          //    Bitwise-OR the result `r` with:
        r<<c))    //    result `r` bitwise left-shifted by the current `c`
```

Comment: 44 bytes is all we need! Taking a stream of `Long`: `s->Long.bitCount(s.reduce(1l,(a,e)->a|a<<e))`.

Comment: @Jakob Thanks! I always forget about `.reduce` (and `.bitCount` as well I might add.. >.>) -39 bytes right there! :)

Comment: Also I just made an [arbitrary-precision version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167311). Looks like the cheapest way to do it is still with a bitmap rather than sets.

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 21 bytes

```apl
⍴∘∪⊢+.×1-2×2(⍴⍨⊤∘⍳*)⍴
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/7VHbhEe9Wx51zHjUsepR1yJtvcPTDXWNDk830gAJ96541LUEJNm7WUsTKPD/Ud9UoI40IMWFlfnfUMFIwYgLRBormCiYKpgpmAN55kC@BVDEEMi3UDA0ULAEAA)

### Explanation

```apl
2(⍴⍨⊤∘⍳*)⍴
```

A function train equivalent to `{((⍴⍵)⍴2)⊤⍳(⍴⍵)}`, which generates a matrix that has the binary representations of 0 to the length of the input as columns

```apl
1-2×
```

Maps `1`s to `-1`s and `0`s to `1`s

```apl
⊢+.×
```

Matrix multiplication with the input, which gives an array of all possible sums

```apl
⍴∘∪
```

Remove duplicates, then count

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 85 bytes

Another Java port of [*xnor*'s answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/164577). Like the original answer, this uses an arbitrary-precision bitmap so that there's no upper limit on the size of a subset sum.

It's a lambda from a sequential `java.util.stream.Stream<Integer>` to `int`.

```java
s->s.reduce(java.math.BigInteger.ONE,(a,e)->a.or(a.shiftLeft(e)),(u,v)->u).bitCount()
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##XVPbitswEH12vkKPMijCchzZ3kugLS0UennYx2VZtI6cderYwZJTwpJvz85IyropWGh0Zs7MGWm8VQc1367/nPfjS9tUpGqVMeSnajryNosCaKyysNVNp1qyBQYfbdPyeuwq2/Qd/xaMu8ln7KDVjj@47e57Z/VGDytGLhapyf3ZzFeGD3o9Vpo66k7ZV/652YQo/vvXV0YV0/F8pXg/UMXNa1PbH7q2VMcxoyM7gG@M@Utjv/RjZ2l8jm5n/ys/9M2a7KApCoKabvP4RNSwMTH2GIVij0@AVspoQ@5Jp/@Sf3GMi94EI@mJfZjTacnI9F1H5FfHBSOZi5KMXDyACQcL5yldoHT24ipd7jyFg4ULAVskQAkxJThSwMoUcXBkAEjpaGXhtiUuSJRjdiiVg52BLXBBdIEVUCuwJabPLkJyZErPxgCsBZ4cIUgkgZALv1LfTCAVmd9RWYGCUi8Ky6bC41kZZCX@joCS@TpLFLDwpRfSCytLd00F6velUCbKRRJ6Jd4oRsOSZaiT@PZQOba@hPOy8GpTwDO8WXwjwIXwC7EymQShjbkLGXpKvDK8BHx7/xInnMCo7gdCP4bIjdYzufEj5icvejgaq3e8Hy3fw1zatqM1V/t9e6TTr/RpGNTRhD@KujRxHN9inRl8p/M7)

Note that the combiner (the third argument to `reduce`) is unused since the stream is sequential. The function I chose is arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), <strike>54</strike> 52 bytes

```julia
V->(~W=W==[]?0:∪([n=W[] -n].+~W[2:end]))(V)|>endof
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVFBTsMwELznFT4mwkWxY6/tSim/aA6RD5WgUlEJFYIb6rlP4A08qx8JO95AhaKVx7M7u@PN88fxsKN538/b1aY@D/3Q92N@aNfXy3c9Tv0wZrWa8v3deRjt@ml6zE1Tb5vPDcPX/fyyO9Wnt8P0fpyul6@9VlVdjUYrm7Wc/2G44U4rp5XXirQqdNJ/H66cN6XElKpURFQwp/zSKBQ6Fs6UPGPTcn1pyaxlIlmQzDomiIomxXJ4BHcJ6MtDAmPH2CC4OqI9HLOa0Nv9WghQkqhRgFmcCaC4EbEgGAkrz1hE0ckJZxGGrJjCWGuEd2mx1cqmWOJkjoeBTkZ3JMZSKguK8C@jYBN2IUKWsEtUc1Ba5rTyPDjH0z3ffRS3lnmHteJPMW@MBLjU3gwBo3ek5U2tOMMSPBaRq6aZfwA)

(*-2 bytes by replacing `¬` with `~`, thanks to [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/167872/2d-array-middle-point/167902#comment405656_167902)*)

Works for all test cases. Makes use of broadcast to collect all possible sums, then counts them.

Explanation:

```julia
function g_(V)
  function inner(W)  #named ~ in golf version to save bytes
    W == [] ? 0 :    #return 0 when input empty (base case)
    ∪(               #unique elements of
      [n=W[] -n]     #take the first element and its negation
      .+             #broadcast-add that to each element of
      inner([2:end]) #sign-swapping sums of the rest of the array
     )
  end                #returns the list of unique elements out of those sums
  return endof(inner(V)) #return the length of that list
end
```

---

Older solution:

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 64 bytes

```julia
N->endof(∪([2(i&2^~-j>0)-1 for i=0:~-2^(l=endof(N)),j=1:l]*N))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVJLasMwEN3nFFoVucggyfoGnCPkAsGBQGuwcZ0Q2m3WOULP0GPlIu48jUvoYtDzm3kzbyYZv6bhFJa@Xfb17n1@O/fycf@RByuHF3u81eNOV7UR/fkqhlZvb7U9yqnlwn1VqbE126l7Jbh8nC7ych3mz2l@3L97JTZyczBK2E7x@x/GJ26UcEp4JYIShSbCFM4UOpeqUDCl/KqMhU6FMyVP2GiqR0Em1hKRLUhiHREhFE1O5fEI6hLRl4ZEwo6wQVB1QntYJHVAb/dnIUIZWI0CzKJMBEWNAgmi4bC8xipKjl84SzBk2RTGWsO8y6stzachieM5HgYaHt0ENpZzOVCCfx4Fm7ALEbIBt0Q1RcjrHM3rwTlW9/TtE7u1xDucFT8N8cZwgMv6aQgYvVNYd9LsDEfwOES3ob/FLw)

Works for input arrays with length upto 63 (so doesn't work for the last test case, which is fine according to OP).

Explanation:

```julia
function f_(N)
  endof(                            #length of
        ∪(                          #unique elements of
          [
           (i & 2^(j-1) > 0)        #check j'th bit (from right) of i
           * 2 - 1                  #convert bit value from (0,1)=>(-1,1)
           for i = 0:2^endof(N)-1,  #where i is numbers 0 to 2^length(N)-1
           j = 1:endof(N)           #and j is 1 to length(N) (i.e. the bits in i)
          ]                         #so we have a matrix [-1 -1 -1;1 -1 -1;1 -1 1;...]
          *                         #matrix multiply that with the input array, 
          N                         #thus calculating different combinations of 
         ))                         #sign-swapping sums
end
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), <s>90</s> 74 bytes

*-16 bytes thanks to [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)*!

```
f(A)=unique(∑_{j=1}^a(-1)^{floor([0...2^a]2/2^j)}A[j]).length
a=A.length
```

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/macn8ggqsp)

Brute-forces all possible sums; then counts the number of distinct sums.

The exact choice of `+` or `-` is encoded in the binary digits of `i`, ignoring the zeroth bit because Desmos arrays are 1-indexed.

Comment: [74 bytes](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/oegvqdkk85)

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Babel Node)](https://babeljs.io/), 64 bytes

```javascript
F=([f,...r],s=[0])=>f?F(r,s.flatMap(x=>[x+f,x])):new Set(s).size
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVHLboJAFN33K2YJ6RUZ5sFMG@zOXVddEhZoobEhYoS0pj9Pz2VojDZ6c/E85pzBz/qrHvbnw2lc7epd062O/XszTdsiKltKkuRc0VCUaRUXm/ZlG51pSNquHl/rU3QpNuXlsaVLFcdPx@ZbvDVjNMTJcPhpprEZxn09NKIQUU1ijEWxEfv@OPRdk3T9R7SN6pjx54c/aVRKyioS@h6bUXuDarr5gPf/XAqMIUs52OyWViRBStAeQoutyHC0uTslB@2I5RZbpuShMtxlvRZXoVeIcCiRkZBpioMAWAsQmJuX4clJ5IaE8tg5x0HOA7UD7ySkcFtYpIYeUijZaYObBZwFJmcIB1kYchkm07NkMTkdNjdzXCgLpTg2kwHXfqmVzjYNiw45hguoEK1sKOahxtdx/xDFNbkum5i1wDSrMdYvOWm4Hjfnqxv8Ni60zYBrPCtsBVzKMIz59FqIn/lsZ5c7paEZvwTDL4L/vTxz8fQL)

This won't work for last testcase.

---

More effective solution (works on last testcase):

## [JavaScript (Babel Node)](https://babeljs.io/), 71 bytes

```javascript
F=([f,...r],s=[0])=>f?F(r,[...new Set(s.flatMap(x=>[x+f,x]))]):s.length
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVFNT4NAEL37K/YIcUpY9oNdDfXWmyePhAOtUDUEmkK0/x7fsBiDBiYD72PmLXzUn/V4ur5fpt2xPjbdrh9em3k@FFHZUpIk14rGokyruNi3T4foSiXAvvkSL80UjUnb1dNzfYluxb683bd0q@K4ih/GpGv68/Q2T804neqxEYWIahJTLIq9OA39OHRN0g3n6BDVMeOPdz/SqJSUVSR0TFtsQe0G1bS5wPt/LgXGkKUcbLalFUmQErSH0KIrMrza/JmSg3bEcosuU/JQmW0WrzDfIUFGQqYppgCwFiAwtzTDlZPIDQnl0XPeBTkX1A68k5DCbWGRGnpIoWSnDW4W8C4wOUMYZGHIZahML5LV5HTonMxxoCyE4rWZDLj2a6x0sWlYdNhjOIAKq5UNwTzUuB3nD6s4JsdlE7MWmGY1yvp1TxqOx8n56AbvxoW0GXCNZ4WugEsZijGf/gbiZ57t7HqmNCTjj2D4Q/CvyzMXz98)

---

This won't work in a real browser due to [`Array#smoosh`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-flatMap/pull/56).

Thanks to Bubbler, `[x+f,x-f]` -> `[x+f,x]` saves 2 bytes.

Comment: You can use `[x+f,x]` in place of `[x+f,x-f]` ([proof by JungHwan Min](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/164513/78410)).

Comment: +2 bytes for ES6 version: `F=([f,...r],s=[0])=>f?F(r,[...s,...s.map(x=>x+f)]):new Set(s).size`

Comment: @Neil, and... `[...s,...s.map(x=>x+f)]`, `s.concat(s.map(x=>x+f))`, and, `s,s.map(x=>s.push(x+f))` share same length...

Answer (score 0):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 73 bytes

```
func[b][s:[0]foreach n b[foreach m s[s: union s reduce[m + n]]]length? s]
```

Port of Dennis' Python 2 answer.
Does not handle the last test case.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYuxDoMwEEN3vsJ7F1JKKCz9h66nG0pIClI5UALfn16HSlSdbD/b0Q/57gfiInQ57OKoZ0odlRyW6B9uhKCnr5@RtMQu0yJIiH7YnacZJwgzv7w8t/GGxHmNk2wIIIMzF8f0lytcUMOiOfAKRqlR3urCqlaof36N8is@O6tqSrSc3w)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 9 bytes

Saved 1 byte thanks to @Shaggy

```
à mx â ÊÄ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///AChdwKhcOLFA53HW75/z/aUEfBXEfBSEfBQkfBWEcByDUDsw0NdBQsYwE) This is a slightly modified port of [Dennis' Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/164512/70894), credits to him for the idea. Explanation:

```
à             Take all non-empty subsets of the input array 
  mx           and sum them
     â Ê      Return the amount of unique sums
        Ä      plus one (to account for the non-empty subset)
```

Comment: Save a byte with `à mx â ÊÄ`

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
Çσ▓╥7Cφ1╝╥ò1
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=80e5b2d23743ed31bcd29531&i=[1,+2]%0A[1,+2,+2]%0A[5,+5,+5,+5]%0A[1,+2,+3,+4,+5,+6,+7]%0A[3,+1,+4,+1,+5,+9,+2,+6,+5,+3,+5]%0A[1,+7,+2,+8,+3,+1,+6,+8,+10,+9]&a=1&m=2)

Doesn't handle the last test case in acceptable time.

Explanation (unpacked):

```
0]s{cN\{+K$uF% Full program, implicit input
0]s            Put [0] under input (array of sums)
   {        F  Foreach:
    cN\          x -> [x, -x]
       { K       Cartesian join:
        +          Add
          $u     Flatten and unique
             % Length
               Implicit output
```

Comment: [8 bytes](http://stax.tomtheisen.com/#p=b3a23a0cc21a7204&i=[1,+2]%0A[1,+2,+2]%0A[5,+5,+5,+5]%0A[1,+2,+3,+4,+5,+6,+7]%0A[3,+1,+4,+1,+5,+9,+2,+6,+5,+3,+5]%0A[1,+7,+2,+8,+3,+1,+6,+8,+10,+9]&m=2) Following a similar solution to what Dennis came up with using Jelly

Comment: @Multi Post it yourself, you were probably not even inspired by this one.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>236</s> <s>208</s> 204 bytes

- Saved <s>twenty-eight</s> thirty-two bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat).

```c
*s,i,g,n;S(w,a,p,_)int*p,*w;{if(_-a)for(_[p]=2;_[p]--;)S(w,a,p,-~_);else{for(*s=0,i=a;i--;)*s+=~(p[i]*2)*w[i];s++;}}f(w,a)int*w;{int p[a+1],r[g=1<<a];s=r;for(S(w,a,p,n=0);g--;wmemchr(r,r[g],g)||++n);w=n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZDRaoMwFIavt6c4FApJPIKxa11J8xS7dCLiqgvMTLTghbWv7pJ0vRhlpiGQhHzn/3JShnVZzjPrUWGNWryRAQtsMadKn1iLbBCjqkgeFrT67kietpmMhV3CUNAbHV5yKo5f/XG0EOtlhEoWQlmG9YG8kDZVGYspG8wq@iAQ01TZYqexDn2CNi0CnmGX1pIfDoXhZCds4E2jZURFbUKH5tiUnx3pLJxhTc/nINBUDFKLaW4KpQkdn5/azsRWZFWRdN1nFCSsP971CmHFEWJYGIapCDHVaUZH8NEwIUBMqfApl3LulYtWq9x4lHsEOx9U@uiHlNd3bxBeELYIO4TE2@X/tFMmHqUp5y6Bu5C9yzRR9mDutn@VPtoqOfd3mbjCV/wN3Lk9j64feNflIu2UkVVO8w8)

Comment: @ceilingcat Thanks; did not know you could drop the `int` in global pointer declarations in gcc.

Comment: It is a (mis)feature of K&R, which technically shouldn't be allowed if we're using `wmemchr()` but gcc is very permissive.

Comment: @ceilingcat Would a strict C99 compiler not accept such K&R remnants?

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 27 bytes

```
+`\d+ ?
*@$%"$&*
%O`.
D`
.+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/XzshJkVbwZ5Ly0FFVUlFTYtL1T9Bj8slgUtP@/9/QwUjBWMFEwVTBTMFcwA)

### Explanation

```
+`\d+ ?
*@$%"$&*
```

For each number, remove the space after it if there is one,. Then split the line into two, one with the number replaced with that many `@`s, and another with the number replaced with that many `_`s. Loop until no more numbers exist. That generates all combination, albeit with some duplicates.

```
%O`.
```

For each line, sort the characters. With this, there is a 1-1 correspondence between a sum and this "`@_`" representation.

```
D`
```

Deduplicate the lines.

```
.+
```

Count the non-empty lines.

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `L`, 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ʠʂU
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#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)

##### Explanation

```python
ʠʂU  # Implicit input
ʠ    # Powerset
 ʂ   # Sum each
  U  # Uniquify
     # Length
     # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata) + `-n`, 3 bytes

```
ŋ∑ũ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFNtJJurpKOgpJunlLsgqWlJWm6FsuPdj_qmHh05ZLipORiqNiCm7XRhjoKRrFcYArOAiGEmDmcaayjYKKjYKqjYKajABI1Bis1AZNAUUuwIjMwGyhlCtFnDha1AAsZgqWBbEMDoPJYiCsA)

```
ŋ∑ũ
ŋ       Non-deterministically negate some elements of the input
 ∑      Sum
  ũ     Unique values
```

`-n` counts the number of possible outputs.